# Webforms: Can I include aspx files like MVC which use RenderPartial or like include in asp classic?

Tags: c#, asp-classic, webforms

I am programming in WebForms not in MVC.

My intention is to do what in MVC we have RenderPartial and can include Views.

In asp classic we have the instruction include to include specific cod

I know in Webforms we have ascx (User control) but my question is:

Do we have something similar in WebForms? I dont want to use (if it is possible) UserControls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, investigating, I discovered yesterday the templates of JQuery, I think it is more or less what I was looking for.

I set u an url which you can find some samples what I wanted:

[Templates in jquery](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template)

Then I can load data using ajax.